# CitraTest vs Selenium/Cucumber

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, cucumber

I have used Selenium/Cucumber in the past for automated testing and it works great. My new company is using CitraTest (which I have not seen yet).

Is there anything CitraTest does that Selenium/Cucumber does not do or anything Selenium/Cucumber does which CitraTest can't do?

Comment: Welcome Jo-Anne. I've edited your question to make it less opinion-based so it doesn't get closed: please take a look at http://sqa.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask for more information about asking good questions for this site. Questions that ask "Have you ever used X?" and "What is your opinion of Y?" will usually be closed very quickly.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're asking for - are you just after a comparison chart or graph? I'm not sure if they can be compared tbh, because it looks like CitraTest is for desktop applications, not web-based applications like Selenium... so they're very different from the off.

Comment: Given I have not used CitraTest or have any information about it besides what is on their website, I will take any comparisons between the two if someone has used them both.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I have used Citratest/ICDefine for several years.
We have used it for testing of Windows and Web applications.
You define the interaction via keyboard input and response of the test object.
It may be in terms of text or images. It recognizes lots of fonts or you may make an image of desired reponse.
Actually you may use it where a GUI is involved.
I had some experience with Selenium and got the experience that it defines the behaviour more on a technical level.